# Javascript - Loop with pauses inside

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want this to happen in a infinite loop, that I can exit at some point, but thats not the point..

So I have a list of dom elements with either video, or image.

I first look, is this an image, if so:

```
Display the image for X seconds
Then continue
```

If its a video

```
I play the video, and on the onend event, I continue
```

Now I start the proces again, and look again ,video or image? So the flow goes on forever, when it reaches the end, it just goes to the first element.

Now doing all that is not the problem, but putting that inside a loop and pausing for X amount of time, or till the video is done playing, there im stuck.

This is what it would look like:

```
func = () ->
console.log "Loop started, now wait X seconds"

delay 3000, ->
    console.log "OK, I waited 3 seconds, now lets go on"

delay 1000, ->
    console.log "Cool, I waited another second, now lets go on"
console.log "Ok, nothing to do, lets start again.."
func()
```

So this loop should in this case restart every 4 seconds
Any ideas for methods that I can look at?

Comment: Never, ever use an infinite loop. If that's the solution you think you need, look at the problem differently...

Comment: Look up `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`.

Comment: Try to use jplayer jquery plugin http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: I will need to have an infinite loop, its a player playing content until it needs to stop (when the user tells it to)

Comment: not sure how settimeout and setInterval will help. Sure you can check lets say every second and then move on the next element. but it must pause when an image displays. using setInterval it will just do it every x seconds. thats missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be structured like this:

```
status = 'nothing'

function loop() {
    if status == 'nothing'

        if next item is image
            show image
            status = 'image'
            countdown = 1000 // time to display the image

        if next item is video
            play video
            videoIsEnded = false
            status = 'video'
            video.onend = function { videoIsEnded = true }

    if status == 'image'
        if countdown-- < 0
            hide image
            status = 'nothing'

    if status == 'video'
        if videoIsEnded
            hide video
            status = 'nothing'
}

setInterval(loop, 1000) // check the status every second
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an infinite loop.

Use [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) instead:

```
    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();


    // usage: 
    // instead of setInterval(render, 16) ....

    (function animloop(){
      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      render();
    })();
    // place the rAF *before* the render() to assure as close to 
    // 60fps with the setTimeout fallback.
```

In order to pause you might use a timestamp:

http://jsfiddle.net/q7qrP/1/